# Create dummy based on two conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, dummy-variable

I have a df where my observations are grouped by their ID's.

I wan't to create two dummies, both on a group level (within same ID).

An example of my df is:

| ID | minority | sentencing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 0 | 20 |

I need the first dummy, "stricter" to be equal to 1 if an observation with minority = 1, has a higher score on the sentencing column than the other observations with matching ID's. stricter is equal to 0 otherwise, as would be the case with the minority with ID = 1.

The second dummy, "leanient", is the opposite. It is equal to 1 if the sentencing is lower than the other observations with the same ID.

I tried with the code under, but I got 0 on all observations:

```
library(tidyverse)

# stricter

df <- df %>%
    group_by(ID)%>%
    mutate(stricter = ifelse(minority == 1 & sentencing > sentencing & minority == 0))
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT:
@r2evans had the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what is not working:

```r
    mutate(stricter = ifelse(minority == 1 & sentencing > sentencing & minority == 0))
#                                            ^^^          ^^^^
```

The two references to `sentencing` are both vectors and comparing self-with-self. Shown differently, it's effectively

```r
dat$sentencing[1:3]
# [1] 10  5  5
dat$sentencing[1:3] > dat$sentencing[1:3]
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
c(10, 5, 5) > c(10, 5, 5)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

What I think you *mean* is along the lines of *"**this** `sentencing` compared with **all other** `sentencing` values"*, which cannot be done as directly in a vectorized fashion. There are several ways around this, including `outer(..)`, but I think perhaps the easiest to visualize will be to `sapply(sentencing, function(sen) ...)` where inside the function, `sen` refers to *each individual value* and `sentencing` refers to the whole vector (within the group) of values.

Try

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    stricter = if (all(0:1 %in% minority)) +(minority == 1 & sapply(sentencing, function(sen) any(sen > sentencing[minority == 0]))) else 0L,
    lenient = if (all(0:1 %in% minority)) +(minority == 1 & sapply(sentencing, function(sen) any(sen < sentencing[minority == 0]))) else 0L
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#      ID minority sentencing stricter lenient
#   <int>    <int>      <int>    <int>   <int>
# 1     1        1         10        1       0
# 2     1        0          5        0       0
# 3     1        0          5        0       0
# 4     2        0         20        0       0
# 5     2        1         15        0       1
# 6     2        0         20        0       0
```

Note: I preface the `sapply(.)` with `if (all(0:1 %in% minority))` because I want it to be robust to `ID`s that do not have both values of `minority` found, where lacking one may reduce the value of the calculation (if not error).

Side note: it appears you are using `0`s and `1`s as boolean indicators, not ordinal or continuous. Because of that, for declarative reasons, I find it better to use true `logical`s:

```r
dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(
    stricter = if (all(0:1 %in% minority)) (minority == 1 & sapply(sentencing, function(sen) any(sen > sentencing[minority == 0]))) else FALSE,
    lenient = if (all(0:1 %in% minority)) (minority == 1 & sapply(sentencing, function(sen) any(sen < sentencing[minority == 0]))) else FALSE
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), minority = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), sentencing = c(10L, 5L, 5L, 20L, 15L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: @r2evans. Acorrding to OP's condition: ' `leanient` is equal to 1 if the `sentencing` is lower than the other observations with the same `ID`', in row 5 `sentencing` is 15 and it is not lower than 2 (in row 6 with the same `ID`). Should `leanient` not be 0 here? This is the output of @Ben comment.

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading it wrong, @TarJae ... row 6 sentencing is 20, so `15 < 20`, right?

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry I missed to copy the last 0. Thanks for clarification!